# On windows pip install dlib gives error - Failed building wheel for dlib

Tags: python, pip, face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to run face recognition opensoruce code. I get errors for "pip install dblib" - 1) "Failed building wheel for dlib" and 2) "Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects".

FYI laptop OS- Windows 10, installed Python 3.11.4, g++ 6.3.0, pip 23.2.1, cmake 3.27.6, Addeded path to the environment variables C:\Users\9500523\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts for cmake.exe and python.exe.

I searched and tried all available solutions, such as pip install cmake, py -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel and pip install dlib -vvv,  install MinGW for C/C++, path in environment variables for cmake and pythonbut still same error. Please help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Solved - I Install the Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC) compiler toolset.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/2695

Suchir2004 commented on Apr 7

> Download the dlib files Link -
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/11Hip8-llWEm5GN3_u4ibI09unL7xCw0g/view?usp=drivesdk
> And just copy the path of that file and paste it into the terminal.
> Stable version is 10 among all files that you have been downloaded
> from the link
>
> In terminal you just need copy the path of that particular file; there
> are 4 files the choose one which is suitable for your computer work on
> windows.